# How do I collaborate in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

my friend and I want to make a big project on Arduino, but we want to make it on the same file but with 2 different computers. does anyone know how to do that? thanks!

Comment: Use a Version Control System. I've used several over the years, but over the past five or six, I've been using `git`. You can sign up for a free [Github](https://github.com) to store your repositories.

Comment: thanks, we'll try that out, but do you know if there are any other solutions than GitHub?

Comment: Several. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to do some research.

Comment: thanks, but do you have some keywords that could lead us in the right direction?

Comment: "Version Control System", per my very first comment.

Answer (score 0):

For collaboration in Arduino projects, I have found using GitHub is the most effective and convenient way. An alternative to this is using Arduino Web Editor and share your URL to your friend.
https://create.arduino.cc/editor

Hope you find these two ways helpful.